# can i draw a boundary class(as interface) instead of a controller class in sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I'm trying UML and its all boring design patterns.
i have an actor requesting to login through interface(a boundary), do i have to draw a controller class after my interface and control this request or the interface is just enough?
what are the problems of using an interface class as a controller class?
can anybody show me where exactly i should  use a controller class in my sequence diagrams?
this is a simple image:[image]

Answer (score 1):

In an U.M.L. Sequence Diagram you may use any class, wheter is "Interface", "Controller" or "Data Access", or more generic class.

Just because a class its a "Boundary" / "Interface" or a "Data Access" class, doesn't means it doesn't do any operations, at all, as many software analysts think.

Instead, the "interface" class do operations that are restricted to its own function, like calculating a window area to be painted, or a "data access" class making a summary of a column.

```
.....................................................................................
..+-------------+....+---------------+....+----------------+....+-----------------+..
..|  <<actor>>  |....| <<interface>> |....| <<Controller>> |....| <<Data Access>> |..
..|    User     |....|  LoginWebPage |....|   LoginWebPage |....|   LoginWebPage  |..
..+------+------+....+-------+-------+....+--------+-------+....+---------+-------+..
.........|...................|.....................|......................|..........
.......+-+-+...............+-+-+...................|......................|..........
.......|   |...Enter().....|   |.Draw()............|......................|..........
.......|   +==============>+   +====+..............|......................|..........
.......|   |...............|   |....|..............|......................|..........
.......|   +<--------------+   +<===+..............|......................|..........
.......|   |...............|   |...................|......................|..........
.......|   |...Login(......|   |...................|......................|..........
.......|   |...UserName,...|   |.................+-+-+..................+-+-+........
.......|   |...Password)...|   |...Validate()....|   |..Seek(UserName)..|   |........
.......|   +==============>+   +================>+   +=================>+   +===+....
.......|   |...............|   |.................|   |.......User.......|   |...|....
.......|   |...............|   |.................|   +<-----------------+   +<==+....
.......|   |...............|   |.................|   |..................|   |........
.......|   |...............|   |.................|   +===+..............+-+-+........
.......|   |...............|   |.................|   |...|.Compare()......|..........
.......|   +<--------------+   +<----------------+   |<==+................|..........
.......|   |...............|   |.................|   |....................|..........
.......+-+-+...............+-+-+.................+-+-+....................|..........
.........|...................|.....................|......................|..........
.........X...................X.....................X......................X..........
.....................................................................................
```

This is a very simplified, even incomplete example. It can have more classes interacting, and more actions ( "arrows" ) among those classes. But, the general idea is to have a look of how interact.

Sometimes, the same class may have, internally, the functions of both Interface & Controller classes.

Cheers.

Comment: Which tool do you use to draw your UML diagrams?